# How to make sql database update if entry exists and if not, insert a new record

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a problem in my code, it's a tic tac toe game which saves the high score(points) into a sql database every time user won the game. If the user name doesn't exist,it creates a new one in a list view. I can't seem to find the reason why the points aren't incrementing. Any help?

This is the activity where I try to update the database and increment the points by one if the username already exists. Otherwise, create new.

```
private boolean player1Turn = true;
private int roundCount;
private TextView currentPlayer;
private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];
private int player1Points;
private int player2Points;
private DbHighscoresHelper dbHelper;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ListView mScoreListView;
private SQLiteDatabase scoreDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_board);
    createTable();

    dbHelper  = new DbHighscoresHelper(this);
    mScoreListView = findViewById(R.id.highscore_list);
}

private void createTable() {

    //create the table
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            String btn_id = "button_" + i + j;

            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(btn_id, "id", getPackageName());
            buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
            buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView whoseTurn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.whose_turn);

    if (checkForWin() == true) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Game over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    //checks if the clicked button is empty(empty string), if not, the button is full
    if(!((Button) v).getText().equals("")) {
        return;
    }
    //lets check if its player1turn, puts the mark in the button
    if(player1Turn) {
        ((Button) v).setText("X");
    } else {
        ((Button) v).setText("O");
    }

    if(player1Turn) {
        whoseTurn.setText("Player 1's turn");
    } else {
        whoseTurn.setText("Player 2's turn");
    }

    //one round is over until all the rounds are used(9)
    roundCount++;

    if(checkForWin()) {
        if(player1Turn) {
            winnerPlayer1();
        } else {
            winnerPlayer2();
        }
    } else if(roundCount == 9) {
        draw();
    } else {
        player1Turn = !player1Turn;
    }

}

private boolean checkForWin() {
    String[][] checkBoard = new String[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            //check if the checkboard stuff is in the same place than in the buttons board
            checkBoard[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
        }
    }

    //lets go through all the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //columns, check field to the one next to it and all three of them
        if(checkBoard[i][0].equals(checkBoard[i][1])
                && checkBoard[i][0].equals(checkBoard[i][2])
                && ! checkBoard[i][0].equals("")) {
            return true; //theres a winner
        }
    }

    //lets go through columns
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //columns, check field to the one next to it and all three of them
        if(checkBoard[0][i].equals(checkBoard[1][i])
                && checkBoard[0][i].equals(checkBoard[2][i])
                && ! checkBoard[0][i].equals("")) {
            return true; //theres a winner
        }
    }

    //lets check diagonals
    if(checkBoard[0][0].equals(checkBoard[1][1])
            && checkBoard[0][0].equals(checkBoard[2][2])
            && ! checkBoard[0][0].equals("")) {
        return true; //theres a winner
    }
    //lets check diagonals
    if(checkBoard[0][2].equals(checkBoard[1][1])
            && checkBoard[0][2].equals(checkBoard[2][0])
            && ! checkBoard[0][2].equals("")) {
        return true; //theres a winner
    }

    return false; //we dont have a winner
}



public void winnerPlayer1() {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player 1 won", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     player1Points++;
     enterName(player1Points);
}

public void winnerPlayer2() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player 2 won", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    player2Points++;
    enterName(player2Points);
}

private void draw() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Draw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public boolean enterName(final int points) {
    if(checkForWin()) {
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("You won!")
                .setMessage("Enter your name")
                .setView(editText)
                .setPositiveButton("Apply", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String getText = editText.getText().toString();
                        new backGroundStuff(points, getText).execute();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create();
                alert.show();

    }
    return false;
}


public static boolean doesDatabaseExists(Context c, String scoreDb) throws IOException {
    File dbFile = c.getDatabasePath(scoreDb);
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
    file.close();
    return dbFile.exists();
}

public boolean nameExists(String tableName, String dbField, String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase scoreDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String Query = "SELECT " + highscores.highscoreEntry._ID + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + fieldValue + " = " + fieldValue;

    Cursor cursor = scoreDb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
}


public static class backGroundStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    int points;
    String getText;

    backGroundStuff(int points, String getText) {
        this.points = points;
        this.getText = getText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String...params) {
        SQLiteDatabase scoreDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(highscores.highscoreEntry.COL_HIGHSCORE_TITLE, this.getText);
        values.put(highscores.highscoreEntry.COL_HIGHSCORE_SCORE, this.points);

        Cursor c = scoreDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM highscores WHERE title LIKE '" + this.getText + "'", null);

        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            c.close();
            scoreDB.insert(highscores.highscoreEntry.TABLE, null, values);
        } else {
            c.moveToNext();
            scoreDB.update(highscores.highscoreEntry.TABLE, values, highscores.highscoreEntry.COL_HIGHSCORE_SCORE + "  ?" , new String[] {Integer.toString(this.points)});
        }


        scoreDB.close();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the database to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

When looking for existing rows you used

```
Cursor c = scoreDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM highscores WHERE title LIKE '" + this.getText + "'", null);
```

Shouldn't you use the percent modifiers to make it match "containing" instead of "equals" like this:

```
Cursor c = scoreDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM highscores WHERE title LIKE '%" + this.getText + "%'", null);
```

without the wildcard percent signs you are in effect making a direct match. Also, I'm not sure if case sensitive matches are an issue as well.

```
Cursor c = scoreDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM highscores WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%" + this.getText.toLowerCase() + "%'", null);
```